# Create a scheduled task with powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a scheduled task using a gMSA account via powewershell but I get some errors when I try to register the task. Below you can see my code and the error:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction  "mypath\myscript.ps1"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -At 12:00 
$user =  New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId domain\gmsa -LogonType Password -RunLevel Highest
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "test" -Trigger $trigger -Action $action -User $user
```

This is the error:

```
 Register-ScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect. At line:1 char:1
 + Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "test" -Trigger $trigger -Action ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsof     t/...S_ScheduledTask)
 [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Register-ScheduledTask
```

Comment: I think this `-User $user` is meant to be `<string>` and you're passing an object as argument.

Comment: Try removing the Trigger, create the task without any trigger. I think the error could be related to it.

Comment: Hello, i hvae removed the trigger and the task was created, but i can not add manually the trigger becasues a passowrd is requested sice I use gmsa i don't know the password. Also i saw that the task doesn't work properly, it is on running state but nothing is happening. I think that the task trigger a notepad instead of .ps1 file

Comment: hello, i have created the task, i saved the script under "C" drive and when i run it from that path the thak was created. Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've already configured a logon principal for the task, use the `-Principal` parameter instead of `-User`:

```
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "test" -Trigger $trigger -Action $action -Principal $user
```

Comment: i have changed the "-user" with "-principal " and i receive the same error

Comment: @bogdan09 Did you check if the [gMSA is ready to be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/test-adserviceaccount?view=windowsserver2019-ps) on your current computer? Mathias answer is correct and should work just fine.

Comment: Hello, yes i checked , the output of this command "test-adserviceaccount mygmsa" is "true", also my server is member in that specified group and it si able to retreive the gmsa password